# sqlplus query doesn't save results to file when running from a shell script

Tags: shell, sqlplus

I have a shell script like below. When I am running it manually, the output is appended to files. When i schedule the script to run from crontab, the output is not appended to output files.

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /home/sample

echo "SELECT count (*) FROM Mytable;"| sqlplus -L user/pass@dbname  > sample.txt

echo "SELECT name, age count(*) from mytable "| sqlplus -L lmsuser/lmsuser@LMSDB > sample1.txt
```

Comment: What's the content of your `crontab`?

Comment: 57 * * * * /data/sample.sh >> /data/sample.log

Comment: So which file should the output go to -- `sample1.txt` as in the shell script command, or `/data/sample.log` as in the crontab? I suspect the output goes to `sample1.txt`, while you're expecting it in `/data/sample.log`.

Comment: Output go to sample.txt,while schedule in crontab that query is not running.When I an running manually output is appended to sample.txt, i am not expecting output in sample.log

Comment: Does sqlplus run successfully or you get any error? You might need to set the required environment variables in your script before calling sqlplus. Try something like:
`#!/bin/bash
. $HOME/.bashrc
echo ....
`

Comment: This could be a permissions issue: in the crontab, you're calling the script as `/data/sample.sh`, but if the script didn't have execute permissions, it wouldn't run. I tend to be *very* conservative when running scripts inside crontab: try `/bin/sh -c /data/sample.sh` instead. This won't break even if permissions on your script change.

Answer (score 0):

Cron does funny things with output, because it is explicitly not connected to anything that a human will look at.

```
   cron then wakes up every minute, examining all stored crontabs,  check-
   ing  each  command  to  see  if it should be run in the current minute.
   When executing commands, any output is  mailed  to  the  owner  of  the
   crontab (or to the user named in the MAILTO environment variable in the
   crontab, if such exists).  The children copies of  cron  running  these
   processes  have their name coerced to uppercase, as will be seen in the
   syslog and ps output.
```

I don't know where this takes place; it could be affecting standard out.

Check your email to see if output has been redirected there.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same issue. It usually happens because your cron is not aware of your variables initialized in .profile. Even the path for `sqlplus` is not available, when you run this script via cron. So, to fix the issue, set the cron job in below format, and it will work fine.

```
00 * * * * . ~/.profile && /home/absolut_path_to_script.sh > /home/log_file_path.txt
```

P.S. I've used the . in front of .profile, so that it loads the same. It fixed my issue, and the cron is producing desired output.